# Pipe visual region to external command, not whole line

Tags: visual-mode, external-command

I have a keybinding `nmap <leader>c :w ! wc<CR>`, I wanted to expand it to work with visual regions (not just the whole file). I did so by creating `vmap <leader>c :w ! wc<CR>`, this is mostly fine but I wanted to pipe the selected region, not the whole line in which the region happens to be. I tried `'<,'>w ! wc` and it's still the whole line. I don't know how to tell vim what region of text I want to manipulate, and every online resource talks about doing the selected line, not text.

How do I specify that I want to use the visually selected text, instead of the whole line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pipe partial lines using `!`.

A workaround is to use a function like `system()`.

```
xmap <leader>c y:echo system('wc', @")[:-2]<cr>gv
```

Breaking this down,

- `y` yank the visually selected text, copying it into register `"`
- `:echo ...<cr>` print the result of a function
- `system(cmd, @")` send register contents to an external command and receive output
- `[:-2]` strip an extra newline
- `gv` (optional) re-enter visual mode

Comment: In neovim v0.9.1, using your code verbatim does nothing, and replacing shuf with wc leads to the result of wc replacing the highlighted text. In both cases register " contains the highlighted text as it was. Using vim v9.0, both shuf and wc simply delete the highlighted region, leaving register " with the highlighted text. In both cases I'm using a minimal vimrc, with two lines `let g:mapleader = "\\"` and `xmap <leader>c c<c-r>=system('shuf', @")[:-2]<cr><c-\><c-n>`

Comment: @Le-Kat just updated my answer to answer the actual question

Comment: @Mass did you mean to remove mentioning of `<c-r>=...`?

Comment: It looks like you updated the mapping and didn't update part of the explanation, since now it `:echo`s